# Rewrite /url/path/index.php to /url/path

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I can't quite figure out how to use a regex in my .htaccess file to remove index.php from the end of a URL if and only if it is the last thing in the string.

If the url is example.com/path/index.php, it should turn into:
example.com/path/

But if the url is example.com/path/index.php?blah=0, it should stay the same.

Any help here? I thought this might work, but it doesn't seem to preserve the latter case above:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*/)index.php$ $1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried it - it does remove index.php, but it still removes it if there are more arguments after the PHP in the URL...

For instance, if the URL is:
http://archstl.org/education/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=167&Itemid=258

It is rewritten as:
http://archstl.org/education?option=com_content&task=view&id=167&Itemid=258

For this URL, I'd like to keep the /index.php in the link...

Comment: So whenever there are GET parameters in the URL, you want to keep it as is ? Just trying to make sure I understand your requirements ...

Comment: Yes, exactly (sorry it wasn't more clear)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a rewritecond checking that the query_string is empty